# Разные поддомены для одного сайта

Tags: php, yii2, apache2

подскажите, плиз, можно ли сделать так-
Есть сайт на yii2. Бейсик
Апач настроен, что любые поддомены ведут в Директорию web этого сайта.
Надо что бы он открывался при заходе на любой поддомен, и само имя поддомена рередовалось дальше в параметрах.
Можно такое, и если да, то как?
Спасибо.

Comment: из `$_SERVER` имя поддомена не взять что ли?

Comment: А ну да, чет протупил, сейчас попробовал, в парамсе взял с сервера имя поддомена, и дальше в парамс оно и пошло уже. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось простым, спасибо teran.
В файле params.php
Взял из $_SERVER     имя поддомена и
Передал в одном из параметров, и все.